# PROLOG local stack overflow

Tags: prolog

The following code is giving me a fatal local stack overflow error (after all solutions are found, instead of "no"), and I don't understand why.  I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the `range` predicate, since if I replace it with a list, I don't have the issue, but I don't understand how it's causing an overflow.

```
nqueens(N,X) :-
  pattern(N,X),range(N,Yrange),legal(Yrange,X).

nocheck(_, []).
nocheck(X/Y, [X1/Y1 | Rest]) :-
  Y =\= Y1,
  abs(Y1-Y) =\= abs(X1-X),
  nocheck(X/Y, Rest).

legal(_,[]).
legal(Yrange,[X/Y | Rest]) :-
  legal(Yrange,Rest),
  member(Y,Yrange),
  nocheck(X/Y, Rest).

pattern(1,[1/_]).
pattern(N,[N/_|T]) :- N1 is N-1,pattern(N1,T).

range(1,[1]).
range(N,[N|T]) :- N1 is N-1,range(N1,T).
```

Comment: It generally means that your end condition is never met, and that you should use the `trace` command, followed by your actual query, to step through what is actually happening. You should add what you're actually trying to achieve with your program to the question, as Prolog is goal-oriented and without specifying what you want to achieve, we can only guess.

Comment: You need a `N > 1` condition in the second clause of your `range/2` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

When N in range/2 becomes 1, the following clause should **not** be left for eventual further processing (that will happen on backtracking), since it will become negative and the recursion will not stop anymore.
You can either test for positiveness in the second clause

```
range(N,[N|T]) :- N>0,N1 is N-1,range(N1,T).
```

or - I think - just cut after the first one

```
range(1,[1]) :- !.
```

Another possibility would be to make the predicate deterministic at call point:

```
nqueens(N,X) :-
  pattern(N,X),once(range(N,Yrange)),legal(Yrange,X).
```

Comment: Really should be `N > 1` condition in the recursive `range/2` clause.